# How it's better to translate "The best house" into Latin?

Tags: grammar-choice, english-to-latin-translation

Can I use "*Domus optima*" or "*Domus optimus*" as the equivalent (I do not need a literal translation) of "The best house"? Should "*optima*" be used with a noun "*domus*" or both are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Latin, every noun has a *gender*, either masculine, feminine, or neuter. Adjectives modifying that noun need to have the same gender.

Most nouns ending in *-us* are masculine, but *domus* is an exception: it's feminine. So the proper translation of "the best house" is ***domus optima***.

---

This is the *singular* (a single best house, not several best houses) and *nominative* (the subject of the sentence, like "I" as opposed to "me") form. If either of those assumptions is wrong (e.g. you're talking about several best houses as the object of a sentence), the form will have to change.